# Why simplification gives different result?

Tags: python

I understand that `(31//16)*4`is 4 because `31//16` evaluates to 1 and `1*4` is 4. But if I try to simplify the expression by taking out 4 from numerator and denominator which results in `31//4`. It is equal to 7. Why this simplification results in incorrect value?

Comment: Because multiplication is not the inverse of floor division.

Comment: @Mark what are simplification rules for floor division?

Comment: I'm not sure. In fact, I'm not sure it's not already simplified. This seems like a math problem.

Comment: 4 * 7 = 28 and 4 * 8 = 32, so it's just telling you that 31//4 with floor division is 7...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floor division consists of two operations: mathematical division and rounding down to nearest integer.

In your case 31//16 = 31/16 - (31-16)/16 = 16/16. So If you want to correct simplify you must do it with both parts of subtraction: (31//16)*4 = (31/16)*4 - ((31-16)/16)*4 = 31/4 - 15/4 = 16/4 = 4